# android api to access phone's device info

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is there an android api to access the devices settings->about phone -> help information?  Assuming that the information exists on android handsets, would like to display diagram from help content.

Developing for extremely low tech users and want to provide as much hand holding as possible.

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer in my post.  I know how to get the model information and mfg, what I would like to do would be to access help to display diagrams showing things like charging the phone and adding a sim.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System and Build classes to get this info:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

As an example if you wanted to get the model you could get that info using the Build class by doing the following:

```
String model = android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Linux machine, or install Cygwin for windows, you can use;

```
adb shell cat /system/build.prop | grep "product"
```

which will return values for the following;

```
ro.product.model
ro.product.brand
ro.product.name
ro.product.device
ro.product.board
ro.product.cpu.abi
ro.product.cpu.abi2
ro.product.manufacturer
ro.product.locale.language
ro.product.locale.region
```